# Simple AJAX not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have this AJAX code, but it doesn't seem to throw the 'alert' method. Instead, nothing happens. I looked at it with Fiddler and got this error message:
`{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}`

I'm trying to call a web method in the code-behind called `MyWebMethod`:

```
 $.ajax({   type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/MyWebMethod",
            data: "{" + username + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function() {
                alert("success");
            },

            fail: function() {
                alert("Fail");
            }
 });
```

The web method worked fine when I had a script manager on the page, but I want to remove the script manager and thought that using AJAX would be the best way.

Thanks

Comment: first try it with NO data, call something that will return something like server timestamp...as a string and alert that. Make sure your web method name "username" matches...EDIT: I am trailing the edits on the page...might not be relevent at this point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change `fail` to `error`, you'll get the second alert box.

[Edit] I think if you then change

```
data: "{" + username + "}"
```

to

```
data: "{ 'username': '" + username + "' }"
```

you'll get the first alert, although it's hard to know that without seeing the service you're calling.

Comment: Hi, I changed it to error, and the alert does show. But I'm not sure why it's failing

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't see your edit. That's fixed the problem! However, the web method returns a bool. How can I get this value from the 'success:' section (or from anywhere else in the call)?
Thanks

Comment: To get the data returned in a success, change the success:function() to success:function(data). Depending on your service setup, you will either get a data which is your boolean or a data with a property .d which is your boolean.

Comment: Bingo!Thanks a lot for the help. I used the '.d' property.

Answer (score 3):

You have custom errors enabled in the web.config. Therefore, the exception returned will be generic (mostly blank) and the same every time. This makes it difficult to debug.

To see the real exception, temporarily disable custom errors.  [Here is how to do that for web services only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969097/turn-off-customerrors-for-web-service-only), if you need that granularity.